# Importing HTML string as code for web app

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, web, bottle

I am creating a web app using python/bottle. I have a header template which I use in every subsequent template by calling `%include('header')`.

In every page I have a sidebar column `div` that looks like this:

```
<div class = "div1" id="about" style="width:300px;height:550px;float:left;margin-right: 40px">
    <p class="s2" style="padding-left: 5pt;text-indent: 0pt;text-align: left;">
    CONTENT HERE
    </p>
</div>
```

What I would like to be able to do is move that `div` to the header template, and then have a separate .py that contains the html content. I tried putting the content in a .py file called 'sidebar.py' and creating variables which were multi line strings of html.

So I moved the `div` to the header as follows:

```
<div class = "div1" id="about" style="width:300px;height:550px;float:left;margin-right: 40px">
    <p class="s2" style="padding-left: 5pt;text-indent: 0pt;text-align: left;">
    {{sidebar_text}}
    </p>
</div>
```

and in the 'welcome.tpl' template I added:

```
%import sidebar
%include('header', sidebar_text = sidebar.welcome_sidebar)
```

But the welcome_sidebar object is imported as a string (obviously) and so the elements inside the string are read as text not elements, styles etc.

Is it possible to properly import html code saved in another file to a bottle template in this fashion? If so, how?

Comment: I don't understand what you're expecting to happen.  Templates don't know anything about HTML; they just deal with strings.  What is the output you'd like to see?

Comment: I want to have my content in a separate file that is imported to the template and sent to the relevant sections. The content includes html elements. To store them as variables I put them as strings, but importing them as strings does not work.

Comment: "does not work" how?  If you could show the output (final rendered html) that you're expecting, and the output you're actually getting, that'd help me understand what you're aiming for.

Comment: Ok, cool, I'll do a couple screen grabs